# ERROR H10 al desplegar una app nodejs en heroku

Tags: nodejs, heroku

hola estoy tratando de subir una app nodejs a heroku pero al desplegarla me sale el error H10, tengo el script Start en el package.json y el puerto bien

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('server start in port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

mi package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node src/app.js",
  "nodemon": "nodemon src/app.js"
},
```

[image: Error en al consol]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno me puse a investigar el log de heroku me di cuenta que estaba pidiendo un modulo de mi proyecto que no existia el cual es "../model/user", y el modulo correcto era "../model/User". No sabia que heroku se fijaba en las mayusculas pero bueno todos los dias se aprende algo nuevo.